# Why am I getting a missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed error?

Tags: r

For reference, I'm using an R package called baseballr.

My code is the following:

```
Homeruns <- function(homerun) {
    for (col in 1:ncol(bat_leaders)) {
        Name = bat_leaders[col, "Name"]
        homerun = bat_leaders[col, "HR"]

        if (homerun > 50) {
            print(paste(Name, homerun))
        }
        else if (homerun < 50) {
            print(paste(Name, homerun))
        }
    }
}
```

I guess I'm confused because it goes through and prints the correct results but then throws that error at the bottom.

Also, if there's a more efficient way to do what I'm doing, let me know! I'm just learning, and as a result trying things out.

Comment: What is the error at the bottom?

Comment: Are your row and column indices reversed?

Comment: What do you want to do? You code appears to print if `homerun` is either more, or less, than 50. Is that really the desired output?

Comment: Yup, pretty basic but that’s it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The error specifically says Error in if (homerun > 50) {: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: What is the type of `homerun`?  If it isn't a number, then I can imagine there being an error there.  Note that your entire for loop can probably be replaced with a single inline call to `ifelse`, which is vectorized.  But, that still doesn't explain the error, which only you can explain.

Comment: Error says what it is. `homerun` has missing value (`NA`) where it expect it to be `TRUE/FALSE`. Now the point to debug is how did it get missing value? Check `bat_leaders[col, "HR"]`. Anyway, we all can just be guessing without giving any useful information unless you provide a reproducible example.

Comment: The type says it’s double

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that `bat_leaders` is a data frame. If you want to manipulate data frames, I encourage you to look at the [dplyr package](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/). Much better than loops.

For example, this code will select rows where HR is *not 50* (which seems to me a quicker way of saying either more or less than 50). It will also select the desired columns and rename `HR` to `homerun`:

```
library(dplyr)
bat_leaders %>%
  filter(HR != 50) %>%
  select(Name, homerun = HR)
```

Comment: This was a lot more efficient, thanks! I'll definitely read into dplyr.